# How to select best neural network repetition number in r

Tags: r, neural-network

I am the using `neuralnet` package in R to build a neural network. My code looks like this:

`nn_po5_fold = neuralnet(wheel_spinning ~ L0 + L1 + L2 + L3 + L4 + L5, data = train_fold, hidden = 5, err.fct = "ce", linear.output = FALSE, rep = 3)`.

I specified the number of repetitions as 3. My question is after training the neural network, how can I return the best the repetition number? In other words, when using the neural network to compute the test data set output, how can I select the best neural network models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same question today, and noticed that

```
nn$result.matrix[1,]
```

provides the errors of each repetition. Hence if by "best", you are referring to the minimum error (this is what I believe my assignment asks for) the line of code below should use the model (weights) that has yielded least error in training:

```
compute(nn, ..., rep = which.min(nn$result.matrix[1,]))
```

P.S. I wanted to post this as a comment on the reply which existed, but couldn't due to reputation. But this is a comment since the general idea has been suggested already.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no definite answer to your question, as 'the best' is relative. The return value of `neuralnet` includes all models, so you can check their error (`nn_po5_fold$result.matrix`) or test them against a separate test set.